# Story (from a quiz paper) about a man who falls in love with a girl, not realising that she's a ghost

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read the story in a quiz during my college time, around 2013.

A man discovers a girl who looks shy and then tries to talk to her. The scene was in a train (or near a train station).

Later they kinda become close to each other, but the girl looks like she is still keeping some secret from him. Maybe she refuses or won't accept his love?

There is a scene where the girl try to talk to her mom, but she doesn't respond. The man saw it from outside.

At the end the man confesses, but the girl reveals that she is dead and shows her tomb to him.

Comment: Can you remember which exam board you were being quizzed by?